# There are 3 tables users,winks and favourite

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are three table Please look at this structure

users table

```
====================== 

id(users.id) |username | status
----------------------------------
56           | mark     | 1
----------------------------------
57           | john     | 1
----------------------------------
58           | lina     | 1
----------------------------------
59           | lara     | 1
----------------------------------
```

winks table

```
======================  
wink_id | from_id(fk from users.id) | to_id(fk from user.id) | wink_flag
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 56                        | 57                     | 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       | 56                        | 58                     | 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

favourite table

```
====================== 
fav_id  | from_id(fk from user.id)  | to_id(fk from user.id) | fav_flag 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 56                        | 59                      | 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 56                        | 58                      | 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Want to left join to have data like this.

```
=======================================================================


id  |  wink_flag  |  fav_flg | status
------------------------------------
57  |  1          | Null
------------------------------------
58  |  1          | 1
------------------------------------
59  |  Null       | 1
------------------------------------
```

i am joining this two table winks and fav using left join with users

1. query

when result comes user.id <> 56

Means when i am logged in using 56 user.id

Then i will have all the users row except me here take that i am logged in as 56 user.id

result will be look like this.

```
======================================
id  |  wink_flag  |  fav_flg | status
------------------------------------
57  |  1          | Null
------------------------------------
58  |  1          | 1
------------------------------------
59  |  Null       | 1
------------------------------------
```

how can i write sql query to have like above result.

Help me.

Comment: Go away, come up with what you think you need to do, and then come back for corrections. Don't expect people to write your code for you.

Comment: If the question is "how", then the answer is "with any text editor" :) Otherwise, that reference may help you : http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/ss/mysql_joins.htm

Comment: `http://sqlfiddle.com` put your schema here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some minutes to read the FAQ's and specially the section on [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This is not a rent a coder kind of site, you should show some effort on solving your problem. Show what you have tried so far, does not matter if your query is not correct, maybe you are not to wrong and the query just need some adjustments. Once you post some code then for sure you will have some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `LEFT JOIN` See demo [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0dc7/16/0)

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  (SELECT
     w.wink_flag
   FROM winks w
   WHERE w.to_id = u.id
   GROUP BY w.to_id) AS WINK_FLAG,
  (SELECT
     f.fav_flag
   FROM favourite  f
   WHERE f.to_id = u.id
   GROUP BY f.to_id) AS FAV_FLAG

FROM users u
WHERE u.id != 56
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `LEFT JOIN`

```
   SELECT u.id, w.wink_flag, f.fav_flag, u.status
     FROM users u
LEFT JOIN winks w 
          ON u.id = w.to_id
LEFT JOIN favourite f 
          ON u.id = f.to_id
    WHERE w.wink_flag IS NOT NULL 
       OR f.fav_flag IS NOT NULL;
```

Result:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ WINK_FLAG ║ FAV_FLAG ║ STATUS ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ 57 ║ 1         ║ (null)   ║      1 ║
║ 58 ║ 1         ║ 1        ║      1 ║
║ 59 ║ (null)    ║ 1        ║      1 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0dc7/15)

Comment: When i add one extra user its did not show that extra user to result ?

Comment: @supercool - Can you show what is not working in [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0dc7/15)? (By adding sample data)

Comment: @supercool - In the other solution the static condition is used. (`where u.id != 56`) which is not ideal.

Comment: @hims056 he wants that user logged in data not used in condition and according to [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) that `<>` & `!=` are same